# How to decode XML response from jQuery $.ajax request in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I am trying to create an ajax request to a WebService that returns data given some specified parameters in XML. This seems to work well in IE, but Firefox can't decode the response. I can view the response successfully in Fiddler after decoding also. Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http:/localhost/webservice.asmx/GetTags?groupId=10',
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html('success',response);
            $(response).find("string").each(function() {
                $('#result').append($(this).text());
            });
        },
        error: function(response) {
            $('#result').html('failure',response);
        }
    });

});
```

Is there a way to specify that response needs to be decoded? Or any other way to make it work?

**EDIT:** 
@Nikki9696 - it's not JSON encoded as the data is returned in XML.

@Oleg - The sample XML I can see in the browser if accessing webservice via a URL is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>tag 1</string>
  <string>tag 2</string>
  <string>tag 3</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

The fiddler in TextView returns `�` and a message

> "Response is encoded and may need to
>   be decoded before inspection. Click
>   here to transform."

Once clicked it displays the same XML. I turn off dynamic content compression in the IIS then the XML is visible in fiddler straight away, but FF still can't cope, so that rules out compression.

I played around with the script a little bit, seems like jQuery can default to or guess some parameters, so dataType, for example, is not compulsory. With these settings I get a success message, however it still doesn't know what to do with the data. I tried setting dataType to "jsonp" as suggested in some SS thread (can't find it at the moment, will link it when I do) and the error changes to `missing ; before statement`, I guess because it's not JSON object, but XML. Is there a way to set webservice to return a JSON instead?

**EDIT 2:** I've updated `url` to reflect what actually happened. Sorry I missed it out, made it impossible for anyone to spot it.

Comment: When you say "decode", do you mean it's JSON encoded?

Comment: could you include the xml data which you receive from the web-service back and which you see in Fiddler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use relative URL like `'/webservice.asmx/GetTags?groupId=10'` you had no problem with different domain. It seems to me that you should just fix a litle your JavaScript code. For example the following code

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/WebService1.asmx/GetTags',
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        data: {groupId:10},
        success: function (response) {
            $('#result').html('success:');
            $(response).find("string").each(function () {
                $('#result').append('<br />'+$(this).text());
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            $('#result').html('failure:<br />' + response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

works fine in Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome. If you need I could post the URL where you could download the whole working Visual Studio 2010 project.

**UPDATED:** To return JSON instead of XML from the web method you can replace `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` to the `[ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute (in .NET 4.0 you can do the same in different other ways) and modify JavaScript code to the following

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/WebService1.asmx/GetTagsJson',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { groupId: 10 },
        //dataType: "xml",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#result').html('success:');
            $(response.d).each(function () {
                $('#result').append('<br />' + this);
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            $('#result').html('failure:<br />' + response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually the path wasn't relative, and that was problem. I cut out most of it to simplify the example, and thus made it impossible for anyone to spot. I'll change it to reflect this.

Comment: @Shagglez: The URL path from your question '/webservice.asmx/GetTags?groupId=10' is relative. Moreover you used in you code `jQuery.html()` in a wrong way (see http://api.jquery.com/html/): `$('#result').html('success',response);`. See fixed version in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is:** I tried to make the call from a different domain to my webservice.

**Here are some more details:**
In Firebug looking at the XML tab I noticed that the error returned was `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{757cb587-20da-4d2f-bf80-e3b915a234d4} Line Number 1, Column 1:`, so I looked for this particular message and stumbled across someone having the same issue http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-xml-issues-no-element-found. Here is the part that solved my problem:

> Though it's not clear in the documentation, you can not use AJAX calls to fetch data from other domains.

It occured to me that the reason it worked in IE is that the first time it asked me whether I would allow to make this unsafe call (or some such), and it must have been referring to making an ajax call to a different domain. FF never prompted me about it and probably disabled the call by default.

Making it cross domain compatible is an issue for another day, for now it's doing everything I need.